# Reintepret cast and Pointer deletion

Tags: c++, pointers, exception

I find the following error in my recent implementation.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
 string header="apple"
 float* p = new float[10];
 double*Data = NULL;
p = reinterpret_cast<float*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + header.length());

//fetch data from an another call// - it doesn't matter here as how it is returned.
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
     p[i] = static_cast<float>(Data[i]);
}

//publish the output to the debug window // 

delete[] p; // throws _block_type_is_valid(pHead->nblockuse) crash
 
}
```

Is this is a wrong way to delete the pointer?

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I'm missing the point of your code. It is certainly invalid as it stands.

Comment: There are many assumptions in your code, can you please [edit] your question to include the assumptions you made, and why you made them? Why do you think this would work? What, if any, is the underlying problem you try to solve with code like this?

Comment: @divinas Its part of a big implementation. I have not posted all the details here. When you meant, "it is certainly invaid as it stands", do you see a foreseeable programming mistake in the way as it is, leaving out other assumptions?

Comment: _do you see a foreseeable programming mistake in the way as it is_ Yesss! The line `p = reinterpret_cast<float*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + header.length());` modifies the pointer which had before the address of the heap-allocated `new float[10]`. So, the following `delete[] p;` is [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I have made some changes to the code. Although as I see, this cannot serve as a minimal executable code. It just serves the purpose as whats going on.

Comment: @Scheff I see! Is there a way to free this allocated memory after the reinterpret cast?

Comment: Please, keep in mind that `new` may internally update some kind of book-keeping for its memory management. This administrative data is often stored with a known relative offset to the address returned and stored in `p`. The `delete[]` tries to find and update this book-keeping data. As you mean-while modified `p`, `delete` finds something else, and assuming this is the searched book-keeping data, it does some unpredictable but probably terrible things leaving chaos in your heap memory.

Comment: _Is there a way to free this allocated memory after the reinterpret cast?_ Before you delete data, you have to recover its original address you got by `new`. (Not more or less than that.) If you want to modify a pointer (to do some pointer arithmetic or cast magic), just make a copy of it. Concerning cast magic: This is often close to U.B. as well and should be used carefully and double-checked - or, at best, not used. ;-)

Comment: It looks like `p` might not be aligned after adding `header.length`, so the Undefined Behavior happens right there. You're going to need a `std::align`.

Comment: @Scheff Something like, 

float *q=p;
delete[] q;

Comment: Yepp. Something like this. ;-) And don't forget that `delete[] q;` makes `p` dangling as well so that it must not be used afterwards anymore.

Comment: @MSalters. Does std::align in return point to the original heap address after the reinterpret cast. I think this doesnt overcome what Scheff has said.

Comment: Thanks to all for this discussion.

Comment: @G.DineshNathan: The returned pointer will point **behind** the input pointer , in particular to the first aligned location.

Comment: @MSalters, thanks. This is new information for me. Quite useful I believe. I will check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This somehow sounds like OP tries to prepare binary data consisting of a header and a sequence of `float`s. To achieve this (and overcome the alignment issues mentioned by [M.Salters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64153387/reintepret-cast-and-pointer-deletion/64154051#comment113445048_64153387)), I would use a `std::vector<char>`, resize it to the resp. full size of expected binary output, and then `std::memcpy()` the contents (header and the float values) into it.

My [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate this:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  const std::string header = "FloatData";
  const float payload[] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
  // determine binary size of header and payload
  const size_t sizeHeader = header.size();
  const size_t sizeData = sizeof payload;
  const size_t sizeTotal = sizeHeader + sizeData;
  // prepare binary buffer
  std::vector<char> buffer(sizeTotal);
  std::memcpy(&buffer[0], header.data(), sizeHeader);
  std::memcpy(&buffer[sizeHeader], (const char*)payload, sizeData);
  // dump binary buffer
  std::cout << "Buffer: " << buffer.size() << " Bytes, Dump:\n";
  for (unsigned char byte : buffer) {
    std::cout << ' ' << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (unsigned)byte;
  }
  std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Buffer: 21 Bytes, Dump:
 46 6c 6f 61 74 44 61 74 61 00 00 80 3f 00 00 00 40 00 00 40 40
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e27676a97a48f72)

**Note:**

The only reinterpret-cast left in the code is in:

```
  std::memcpy(&buffer[sizeHeader], (const char*)payload, sizeData);
```

Probably for exactly such use-cases like the one of OP, there are specific exceptions made for `char` (and comparable types like `unsigned char`) concerning the reinterpret-casting.

From [**cppreference.com: reinterpret_cast conversion**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> AliasedType is `std::byte` (since C++17), `char`, or `unsigned char`: this permits examination of the object representation of any object as an array of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the underlying problem, you'll need a way to recover the original pointer `p`. Since your header is variable-length, that means it will need to *end* with a length, and the floats will need to directly follow this length (with zero padding). A possible solution to achieve this zero padding could be to store the length as a `float` (!). You can then get the header length as `size_t(p[-1])`.

Also, in the `new[]`, you'll need extra space for the header and alignment overhead.

Having said that, the **far** easier solution is

```
class Data {
  std::string header;
  std::vector<float> values;
};
```

Comment: This somehow sounds like OP tries to prepare binary data consisting of a header and a sequence of `float`s. To achieve this (and overcome your mentioned alignment issue), I would use a `std::vector<char>`, resize it to the resp. full size of expected binary output, and then `std::memcpy()` the contents (header and the float values) into it.

Comment: @Scheff, indeed yes.

Answer (score 0):

The value passed to `delete` or `delete[]` must be a value returned by `new` or `new[]`, respectively:

```
float* p = new float[10];
// ...
delete [] p;
```

If the code modifies the value of `p` between the `new` and the `delete[]` the behavior is undefined.

If you need a different pointer value based on the value of `p`, do whatever you need to get it, but you **must** either hang on to the **original** value of `p` or be able to recalculate it for the delete. Maybe like this:

```
float* p = new float[10];
float* not_p = reinterpret_cast<float*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(p) + header.length());
// ...
delete [] p;
```