# Reinterpret Cast for a Binary Formatting

Tags: c++, pointers, reinterpret-cast

As a follow up discussion to the following question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64153387/reintepret-cast-and-pointer-deletion/64153761#64153761).

The output console to dump is handled by a generic method

```
HRESULT DumptoOutputConsole(const void* Data, size_t DataSize);
```

From the previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64154051/783907) by @Scheff, if I try to dump the `buffer` using the `DumptoOutputConsole`, I get an exception.

More formally:

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

HRESULT DumptoOutputConsole(const void* Data, size_t DataSize); //Black box implementation

int main()
{
  const std::string header = "FloatData";
  const float payload[] = { 1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f };
  // determine binary size of header and payload
  const size_t sizeHeader = header.size();
  const size_t sizeData = sizeof payload;
  const size_t sizeTotal = sizeHeader + sizeData;
  // prepare binary buffer
  std::vector<char> buffer(sizeTotal);
  std::memcpy(&buffer[0], header.data(), sizeHeader);
  std::memcpy(&buffer[sizeHeader], (const char*)payload, sizeData);

 HRESULT error= DumptoOutputConsole(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer),sizeTotal); // C0000005 Access Violation Exception
  
}
```

The task at hand is to print out the float payload values (stored as IEEE 754 floating point number) in a 4 bytes binary format.

Something like `\\x13L\\x02\\xb6`. My thoughts are on the the argument `sizeTotal`. As, `sizeof(float)=4` the net sum of characters sent to the console is then `sizeTotal` bytes. But this doesn't say about the `4 byte` format for each float values.

Any light on this will be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `&buffer` is the address of the vector instance, not of its contents.

Comment: Ah ok. So ```&buffer[0]``` should point to its content.

Comment: Yes, and so does `buffer.data()`. You used `header.data()` just a few lines earlier...

Comment: Thanks. As a follow up question. Can the vector destruct itself once the function scopt is lost as like usual vectors or does the ```reinterpret_cast``` doesn't  allow point to original location after the casting operation and hence destruction never happens ?

Comment: Casting has no effect on the object you cast *from* (unless there are misbehaving converting constructors or operators involved). The vector behaves like all other vectors.